# View controller release before delegate return

Tags: iphone, delegates

I have a problem. My view controller (ViewController) implement a delegate method of a object (DataPuller, data get from the internet). DataPuller will retrieve data on the internet without blocking user interaction with the view. But when I navigate between screen, in some cases, that ViewController release before DataPuller return the list of objects. The DataPuller return, it checks:

```
if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getCommentDidDownloadFinish:)]) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(getCommentDidDownloadFinish:) withObject:self];
}
```

And the application crash here because ViewController release, it becomes a zombie object. Does anyone have this problem before and how to solve it? I think another way is using NSNotification, but I wonder any other better solutions. Any ideas, solutions are welcomes. Thanks.

Comment: Im not sure it working or not but try put "delegate = nil;" under the viewDidUnload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view controller must remove itself as the DataPuller delegate at some point.  Typicially, this is handled in the dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
     dataPuller.delegate = nil;
     [dataPuller release];
     [super dealloc];
}
```

You may also decide to do this in -viewDidUnload or -viewDidDisappear:.

Comment: Good point, far easier solution. Don't forget to also retain dataPuller in the view controller, of course.

Comment: Darrens answer should always be followed. Won't crash if the delegate is already released and whenever the delegation class is "dealloced" there can be no need for a reference to the delegate. If your DataPuller should pull data whether or not the view needs it right now, you might consider doing a singleton and save the data pulled to the NSUserDefaults, CoreData, .plist etc. I do this for stuff that needs to update in the background on a fixed interval, then I just ask the NSUserDefault (or the place dataPuller saved the data) for the most recent data. Don't know if this applies to you app.

Answer (score 1):

Delegation (usually) implies some sort of ownership - i.e., if you make an object a delegate of another object, usually the delegate object holds a strong reference (i.e., retains) the delegating object.

As an example, a UITableViewController is the delegate of its UITableView. This is okay, because the controller retains the tableview through the "view" property.

If your design does not allow ownership, use notifications, like you already suggested. As a bonus, notifications can signal multiple listeners if you would ever need that.

Don't forget to remove your observer in the dealloc of the view controller!

Comment: No, I did not using retain, I use assign element in CommentDataPuller and ViewController is assigned as delegate property of CommentDataPuller.

Comment: You did the right thing (will edit my answer, it was maybe unclear). Now start using notifications and you're all set.

Comment: Check out Darren's answer - it's better :)